# Makefile, when is $(shell cat file) evaluated?

Tags: shell, makefile

Makefile

```
 a: 
    echo "123" > afile
    cat afile
    # expect output 123, but it's empty
    echo $(shell cat afile)
```

Why does echo output nothing?

Comment: It's a directive to `make`, not the shell, so it has to be executed _before the shell can be started_ (because otherwise the code for the shell to be passed is unknown).

Comment: If you want something to be executed _late_, then escape it so it's a shell directive instead of a makefile directive.

Comment: "If you want something to be executed late, then escape it so it's a shell directive instead of a makefile directive. "
sorry I didn't get it. would you explain in detail?

Comment: `$$(cat afile)` generates the shell syntax `$(cat afile)`, which the shell takes an instruction to read afile while it's running; as opposed to `$(shell cat afile)`, which is an instruction to `make` to start a _separate_ shell whose output is to be used in generating the code to be later passed to the shell actually running the code.

Answer (score 2):

In make, the entire recipe (all commands in the recipe) are expanded before the first command in the recipe is invoked.

Since `$(shell ...)` is a make function, not a shell function, make will expand it before it starts running any commands in the recipe.

You can change it to `$$(cat afile)` and make it a shell operation, and make won't run the `cat`.

Comment: In general it's a code smell for make recipes to use either the make `$(shell ...)` function (because, a recipe is already running in a shell so using make's shell function just leads to confusion like this) or make `$(eval ...)` function (because it is probably not the right way to solve whatever problem you're having).

Answer (score 0):

thank you all. $(shell ...) expanded before recipe executing. make sense.
look following code

```
a: 
    ln -s hello.txt qq
    cat qq
    echo $(shell cat qq)

a1: a
    cat qq
    echo $(shell cat qq)
```

make a1.

why a1 could echo string right? hello.txt contains hello.

Comment: Make doesn't expand ALL recipes in the makefile before starting ANY recipes.  That would be a disaster because many recipes won't actually end up being run at all!  It expands all the commands in _a specific_ recipe, before it starts to run commands in that recipe.  In your example `a1` depends on `a` so before the recipe for `a1` is expanded and run, the rule for `a` is checked.  That is out of date (assuming no `a` exists) so the recipe for `a` is expanded and run.  Then when it's finished `a1` is out of date, so the recipe for that target is expanded and run.

Comment: You can figure this all out on your own with simple experiments, much more quickly than posting here and waiting for an answer.  Instead of using `$(shell ...)` use make's `$(info ...)` function so you see output when expansion happens.

Comment: my bad, I though all $(shell...) was expended by make, before any recipe starts. then my question is in what case could I stop $(shell...) expand? I have tried target have dependency target, (let a depend on b target, b target echo hi), that won't stop $(shell...) expand before run a recipe.

Comment: You should follow the advice everyone is giving you, and _NOT USE `$(shell ...)` AT ALL_.  Then you won't have to worry about it :).  There is no way to prevent make functions, including the `shell` function, from being expanded before the recipe is run.  That is simply not possible.  But since you shouldn't use it anyway, it doesn't matter.

Comment: Dear Sir, thank you so much for the answers. my case is like this.
main make need to print a variable at the end. but the variable depend on sub-make target. since there is no way for sub-make pass variable to main make. so I try to write variable to a file. in main make recipe , it $(eval var = $(shell cat file)).
as my limited knowledge of make. I could not find other way around without using $(shell ..).  would you give me a clue?

Comment: I told you exactly how to do it in my original answer: I said _You can change it to `$$(cat afile)` and make it a shell operation, and make won't run the cat_

Answer (score 0):

after google, find the answer. like MadScientist said avoid $(shell ...).

```
a: 
    echo "123" > afile
    cat afile
    echo `cat afile`
```

Comment: Don't use backticks -- they're hard to nest because they change the behavior and meaning of double quotes, backslashes, and other backticks within them. `$(...)`, or in this context `$$(...)` to protect the `$` from `make`, is better behaved.

Answer (score 0):

```
a: 
    echo "123" > afile
    cat afile
    echo $$(cat afile)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.